# How to increase writes (inserts) without reducing oplog window in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

I have a MongoDB cluster. The cluster is currently writing (mostly inserts) 4k/sec. When I increase the number of inserts from 4k to 5k, I can see oplog window slowly reducing, possibly to 0 if I do not intervene. What are ways I can increase the number of inserts while maintaining oplog window? The cluster is on AWS m5.2xlarge, CPU is running fine (under 20%). Would a more performant instance help in this regard?

Comment: Do you mean a "sharded cluster"? Do you have more than one mongos?

Comment: It is a single replica set.

Comment: Then you may consider a shared cluster in order to distribute the load

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit that is true. ty.